# overflow-y auto and arrow not working together

Tags: css

I have a div with an arrow before it.

the problem is, when I add:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

the arrow disappears.

https://jsfiddle.net/z95frkuv/

```
#n { 
 position: fixed; 
 min-width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 max-height:400px;
 //overflow-y: auto; // need to remove this to see arrow
 border:1px solid #000;
 z-index:3000;
}
#n:before {
 content: "";
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
}
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow:auto` works like `overflow:hidden` when it comes to absolute positioned elements.

In order to overcome it, add a wrapper div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id=n>content<br>content<br>content<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br></div>
</div>
```

And update the css:

```
.wrapper { 
 position: fixed; 

 z-index:3000;
}
.wrapper:before {
 content: "";
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
}

#n{
  min-width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 max-height:400px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yow7wm7r/1/

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what overflow is doing, if an element is defined inside the box, but with css it sticks outside, the overflow will clip it out.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp